# glVertexAttribPointer (Offset?) giving GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl, void-pointers

I have a problem with my code: (OpenGL 4.1 Core Context, I'm using VertexArrayObjects)

```
//This is a member method, vertexArrayObject and vertexBufferObject are of course generated using glGenVertexArrays & glGenBuffers
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, 0);
Draw::debugLogGLError(); // OpenGL Error #0
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
Draw::debugLogGLError(); // OpenGL Error #1282
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
Draw::debugLogGLError(); // OpenGL Error #1282
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

*Draw::debugLogGLError()* simply prints out the latest error code to the console

```
void Draw::debugLogGLError(void){
     std::cout << "OpenGL Error #" << glGetError() << std::endl;
}
```

If I remove the offsets `(void*)(sizeof(float) * 3)` it will run just fine.
So I'm assuming it's the `(void*)` having problems. However it worked just fine before I started to implement this in a class.
I might have missed some code

OS: Mavericks, HD5000, Clang compiler in Xcode

Comment: It seems to be correct, the only thing which differs from my code is: I don't call `glBindVertexArray` anywhere, i just bin my vertex buffer and i call `glEnableVertexAttribArray` after `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: Hm. Still getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I've read when using a  core context Vertex Array Objects have to be implemented

Comment: Can you post the initialization code of your vertex buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer :

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if size​ is GL_BGRA​ and type​ is not GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE​, GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV​ or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV​.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if type​ is GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV​ or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV​ and size​ is not 4 or GL_BGRA​.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if type​ is GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV​ and size​ is not 3.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated by glVertexAttribPointer if size​ is GL_BGRA​ and noramlized​ is GL_FALSE​.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if zero is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER​ buffer object binding point and the pointer​ argument is not NULL​.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if no vertex array object is bound.
```

The first 4 are obviously not the case so it must be one of the last 2. The last one can't be the case as it doesn't always throw the error, and the last one would. So the problem according to the wiki is:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is generated if zero is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER​ buffer object binding point and the pointer​ argument is not NULL​.
```

This would mean `vertexBufferObject` in your code is 0 and thus not a valid buffer object. If this is not the case, I'd think you just stumbled upon a major driver bug.

Comment: Thanks! I've just looked over my code and figured out that `vertexBufferObject` was 0. An embarrassing mistake...